# Inserting a List<> into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an entity `Report` whose values I want to insert into a database table. The following attributes of `Report` have to be inserted:

```
reportID - int
RoleID - int
Created_BY = SYSTEM(default)
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Now the problem is with the 2nd attribute. I have a report with the `LIST<ROLES>` attributes. `ROLES` is a well defined entity which has an `ID` and a `NAME`. From this list I have to extract every role and insert each role's ID into the table.

So my query presently looks as below :

```
INSERT INTO REPORT_MARJORIE_ROLE(REPORT_ID, ROLE_ID, CREATED_BY, CREATED)
VALUES({0}, {1}, 'SYSTEM', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

The C# code from where I am parsing these values is as follows :

```
try
{
    StringBuilder _objSQL = new StringBuilder();
    _objSQL.AppendFormat(Queries.Report.ReportQueries.ADD_NEW_ROLES, report.ID, "report.MarjorieRoles.Add(MarjorieRole")); 
    _objDBWriteConnection.ExecuteQuery(_objSQL.ToString());
    _objDBWriteConnection.Commit();
    _IsRolesAdded = true;
}
```

So please guide me how to add roles from C# function

Comment: have you considered an ORM? With Linq to SQL or Entity Framework you could be up and running with this in half an hour.  There's also nHibernate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*I'm assuming you say **SQL** (structured query language) and you really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual database product) instead - right?*

You cannot insert a whole list as a whole into SQL Server - you need to insert one row for each entry. This means, you need to call the INSERT statement multiple times.

Do it like this:

```
// define the INSERT statement using **PARAMETERS**
string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.REPORT_MARJORIE_ROLE(REPORT_ID, ROLE_ID, CREATED_BY, CREATED) " + 
                    "VALUES(@ReportID, @RoleID, 'SYSTEM', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

// set up connection and command objects in ADO.NET
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, conn)
{
    // define parameters - ReportID is the same for each execution, so set value here
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = YourReportID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RoleID", SqlDbType.Int);

    conn.Open();

    // iterate over all RoleID's and execute the INSERT statement for each of them
    foreach(int roleID in ListOfRoleIDs)
    {
      cmd.Parameters["@RoleID"].Value = roleID;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: yeah yeah you are right...its MS SQL Server
thanks for the help and correcting me there

Comment: How about passing a list as xml? That would solve your problem

Comment: @John: yes - you could send it as XML - but then you'll have to "shred" it inside SQL Server again and that also requires some effort and code ....

Comment: you could maybe use a Transaction, so in case something goes wrong it will rolleback

Answer (score 0):

let say `lstroles` is your `LIST<ROLES>`.

```
lstroles.ForEach(Role => 
   {            
       /* Your Insert Query like 
        INSERT INTO REPORT_MARJORIE_ROLE(REPORT_ID, ROLE_ID, CREATED_BY, CREATED)
        VALUES(REPORT_ID, Role.ID, {0}, {1}, 'SYSTEM', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

       Commit you query*\
   });
```

On a personal note: Beware of SQL Injection.

Comment: You should **NOT** concatenate together your SQL statements! That's opening the barn door to **SQL injection attacks**, and it's also slower from a performance point of view (no reuse of the SQL Server execution plan!)