# Splitting string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm trying to split strings in C# like this

```
COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C
```

should be

```
word1     word2       word3      word4     word5   word5
COMMSTR1 NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1 NAC-NAM-P-C  CHAZEL1 NAT-CBM-P-C
```

In above it contains three words sometime it could contain two words or one word.
How can i get above output. I was trying below but Got stuck.

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string str = "COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C";

                string[] words = str.Split(' ');

                 foreach(string word in words)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}",word);
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

Comment: try change string separator from ' ' to '|' and then use `str.Split('|');`

Comment: are they tab delimited or space delimited?

Comment: is it always split on space (" ") and then on first hyphen ("-")?

Comment: what is the standart?You are using `Split(' ')` but how is this going to help to this one `COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C`?Is it the numbers?

Comment: @DanielA.White space delimited..

Comment: @RoboLover if it only one word I don't want to split it by space just split like COMMSTR1 word1 and NAC-NAM-P-C word2.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer You have asked same question in SQL server and now you have asked in C#. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the logic to split words? Usually words are split by spaces but in your case seems arbitrary.. or at least I don't get it.

Comment: @Sudhakar It's not working with sql-server so I'm trying with c#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try the following, first split it on the space and then use `IndexOf` to get rest from the word. :

```
 string str = "COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C";
 string[] words = str.Split(' ');
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
 foreach (string word in words)
   {
            int index = word.IndexOf('-'); // as per Daniel's suggestion
            list.Add(word.Substring(0,index));
            list.Add(word.Substring(index+1));
    }
```

//For printing

```
    foreach (string tempStr in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tempStr);
    }
```

Comment: i would cache the call to `IndexOf`.

Comment: @Habib.OSU How to print the words I've never worked with List.

Comment: @Habib.OSU I want to store all 6 different words in different variable.

Comment: @Viswanathan make `foreach(var s in stringList){ Console.WriteLine("{0} ",s);}`

Comment: @Habib.OSU But How can i store it in different variables.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer, you can store them in different variable, but I would suggest using List, because probably , you can't predict the number of variable to use for each string

Comment: @Habib.OSU Can i insert this list in a sql server table?

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer, not directly, you have iterate through each item and insert it in the db or create a bulk insert statement, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680910/inserting-a-list-into-sql-server-table

Answer (score 2):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C";

        string[] flag = str.Split(' ');
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        foreach (string f in flag)
        {
            words.Add(f.Split('-')[0]);
            words.Add(f.Remove(0, f.IndexOf('-') + 1));
        }

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", word);
        }

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex with named groups seems like a good fit here:

```
var pattern=
    @"^(?<word1>[^-]*)-(?<word2>[^ ]*) "
    +@"(?<word3>[^-]*)-(?<word4>[^ ]*) "
    +@"(?<word5>[^-]*)-(?<word6>.*)$";
var input="COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C";
var m=Regex.Match(input,pattern);
if(m.Success)
{
    var word1=m.Groups["word1"].Value;
    var word2=m.Groups["word2"].Value;
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2);
```

to split only on the first occurrence of -.
So first you `Split(' ')` and then on `Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2);`

A modified version of @Habib.OSU's answer would then look like this:

```
string str = "COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C";
string[] words = str.Split(' ');
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (string word in words)
{
        list.AddRange(word.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2));
}
foreach(var s in list) Console.WriteLine(s);
```