# Best way to insert a list of values into Database using SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, list

I have a list of urls of products which i extract from a webpage.. And i have another list containing the titles

I want to loop through the lists and insert all the titles & links into a sql server database table..

**basically i want to make multiple inserts with a loop**

I want to loop through both lists and insert (title, url)

what is the best method and how to do it?? Please provide example.. Could someone help please?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a good way to ask a question. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: what did you tried? show us your code and problem.

Comment: I have not tried anything because i have no clue about it

Comment: I know how to insert single rows.. but i dont know how to insert multiple rows from an list

Comment: Question states:  "into a sql server database table", assuming sql server but version would be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting a List<> into SQL Server table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680910/inserting-a-list-into-sql-server-table)

Comment: "I want to loop through the lists and insert" + "I know how to insert single rows" = "an initial attempt at the solution".  Write your loop, and in each iteration of the loop insert one row.  If this works, great.  If it is too slow, or you are getting errors you can't resolve, edit this post to include the code you have, and explain the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how to insert single rows, but I don't know how to insert multiple rows from an list

The *simplest* way is just to insert one value at a time in a loop:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
   for(int i=0; i < urlList.Length; i++)
   {
      string url   = urlList[i];
      string title = titleList[i];
      SqlCommand cmd = new SQlCommand({insert sql here});
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

You could do lots of "elegant" things like bulk imports, etc., but unless performance is a *significant* problem and the SQL is the *biggest* contributor to performance problems, simpler is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL has a handy import/export wizard, here's a walkthrough:

[Import/Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

If you want to generate a list of INSERT statements (ie, the list of URLs is not terribly large), I suggest using EXCEL.  Paste your list of values to insert, and then create a formula to the right of the first row that's something like:

```
="INSERT INTO table VALUES ('"&A1&"','"&B1&"')"
```

Then just copy down the formula to generate all your INSERT statements.

Comment: i want to do this programatically because i will be scrapping a huge amount of links everyday..

Comment: Where will they be getting scraped to, a text file?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a statement like:

```
insert into myurls (url) values
(url1),
(url2),
(url3)...,
(urln);
```

(assuming your sql version supports this).